# Shelves with "trichotomy"

Tags: knot-theory, self-distributivity

A left shelf $(S, \rhd)$ is a magma with the left self-distributive law:
$$
\forall x, y, z \in S: x \rhd (y \rhd z) = (x \rhd y) \rhd (x \rhd z).
$$
Shelves are generalization of [racks and quandles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racks_and_quandles) from the knot theory.

I am looking for examples of shelves with the following additional axiom:
$$
\forall x, y \in S: x \neq y \implies (x \rhd y = y \iff y \rhd x \neq x).
$$
Can a left shelf satisfy this property?

(See also [the follow-up question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/328423) about *racks*.)

Comment: I suggest calling this property the "trichonomy property" or "shelf trichonomy property."

Comment: One follow-up question is whether it always follows from these properties that $x>y$ defined by ($x\rhd y=y$ and $x\neq y$) defines a total order (i.e., it is transitive)?

Comment: If we extend the question to left shelves $(X,*,1)$ that satisfy the identities $x*1=1,1*x=x$ and where the non-unital trichotomy states that $\forall x,y\in X,|\{x,y,1\}|=3\Rightarrow(x*y=y\Leftrightarrow y*x\neq x)$, then whenever $X$ is a linear ordering with greatest element $1$ and $\rightarrow$ is the Heyting operation on $X$, then $(X,\rightarrow,1)$ satisfies the non-unital trichotomy where if $x,y\in X\setminus\{1\}$, then $x\rightarrow y=y$ iff $y<x$.

Comment: The relation that YCor is proposing resembles the total ordering on the critical points in the algebras of rank-into-rank embeddings. If $X$ is a finite linear ordering, then $(X,\rightarrow,1)$ satisfies the non-unital trichotomy, and there some embedding $\phi:(X,\rightarrow,1)\rightarrow\mathcal{E}_{\lambda}/\equiv^{\gamma}$. However, $x<y$ if and only if $\mathrm{crit}(\phi(x))<\mathrm{crit}(\phi(y))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linearly ordered sets when considered as lattices satisfy this property. Suppose that $(X,\wedge)$ is a meet-semilattice with corresponding partial ordering $\leq$. Then $\wedge$ is a self-distributive operation. Furthermore, $x\wedge y=y$ if and only if $y\leq x$. Therefore, the meet-semilattice $(X,\wedge)$ satisfies $x\neq y\rightarrow(x\wedge y=y\leftrightarrow y\wedge x\neq x)$ precisely when $\leq$ is a linear ordering.

**Steps towards a characterization**

The following results will establish that all left shelves that satisfy trichotomy must satisfy a weak version of idempotence. This result is a first step towards classifying shelves that satisfy tricotomy.

**Theorem:** Suppose that $(X,*)$ is a left shelf that satisfies the trichotomy property and which is generated by $x$. Then $X=\{x,x*x\}$. Furthermore, $r*s=x*x$ whenever $r,s\in X$.

A proof of the above theorem is given in [my answer to the follow up question](https://mathoverflow.net/a/328487/22277).

**Theorem:** Suppose that $(X,*)$ is a left shelf that satisfies the trichonomy property. Then whenever $x\in X$, we have $|\{y\in X\mid y*y=x\}|\leq 2$.

**Proof:**  Suppose that $x\in X$ and $$|\{y\in X\mid y*y=x\}|\geq 2.$$ Now let $$A=\{y\in X\mid y*y=x\}\setminus\{x\}.$$ If $a,b\in A,a\neq b$, then
$a*b=b$ or $b*a=a$. Suppose therefore that $a*b=b$. Then
$a*(a*b)=a*b=b$. However, $$a*(a*b)=(a*a)*(a*b)=x*(a*b)$$
$$=x*b=(b*b)*b=x$$ which is a contradiction. **Q.E.D.**